# Merge vectortiles

Tags: mapbox, vector-tiles

Can anyone suggest a workflow to merge Mapbox Vector Tiles (MVT in protobuf) back into a contiguous dataset?

Vector tiles often have polygons and lines beyond their tile bounds (the buffer area). This data often is sliced and deformed. Of course, union and dissolving of overlapping geometries result in a catastrophe.

Mapbox GL and Openlayers seem to have a way to distinguish, which polygon to chose, which to drop, and which to merge. Anyone with an idea, how this could be reproduced, just for debugging use?

I'm aware that the conversion of geodata to MVT is lossy. Especially in small zoom levels, the data is subject to effects of simplification and quantization.

Comment: What kind of catastrophe hits you when you dissolve?

Comment: @user30184 The tiles on the edges are either off a few centimeters (quantization?) or have a slightly different shape. When joining them, the polygons are intersecting with others, have a bigger size, etc. Here is an ![example](https://imgur.com/ofzN2G7) - but I'll try to find worse examples in the dataset.